# How to send image between activities by path android

Tags: android

I try to send image to another activity by path. There is no errors but the image is not visible. I think it's may be problem with sending path but i don't know. The image is in catalog drawable.

Thanks for help

This is my first activity:

```
public void onClickObamaBtn(View v){

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EkranB.class);
    String path = getString(R.drawable.obama);
    Toast.makeText(this, path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    intent.putExtra("president", path);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Ant this is a second:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ekran_b);

    ivObama = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iV1);
    preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("prezydenciUsa", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String path = getIntent().getStringExtra("president");
    Drawable president = Drawable.createFromPath(path);     

    ivObama.setImageDrawable(president);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path what you mean is the `Resource` in `Drawable`, it is an `Resource id` of `int`

You can directly set the image from `Resource` like this

```
 imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.id.obama));
```

I don't see, why you need to pass the `Resource id` , since resources are accessible by all the `Activity`

If you really need to pass the drawable through intent , then do like this

```
 int pathId = getResources().getDrawable(R.id.obama);
 intent.putExtra("president", pathId);
```

Now, get the resource id and set it to `ImageView` like this

```
int pathId = getIntent().getIntExtra("president", -1);
imageView.setImageDrawable(pathId);
```

Comment: But in Drawable i have three different images. In first activity i have three buttons. In Dependency on which button I press I want to in the second activity flashed me different picture. That's why I want to do by path.

Comment: ok. Then use my second approach to pass the drawable through intent. Pass the drawable id intent.putExtra("president", pathId);

Answer (score 0):

```
in this case its better to pass integer value which you will get from first activity as follow

public void onClickObamaBtn(View v){

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EkranB.class);
    int path = R.drawable.obama;
    Toast.makeText(this, ""+path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    intent.putExtra("president", path);
    startActivity(intent);
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ekran_b);

    ivObama = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iV1);
    preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("prezydenciUsa", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    int path =  getIntent().getIntExtra("president",0);


    ivObama.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(path));

}
```